# Tracking open Outlook 2010 emails

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking for a programmatic way (eg: using VBA) to write the Subject texts of emails which are open, or otherwise export opened emails to a file system folder.

Comment: I'm little confused? can you add some more detail info?

Comment: Yes, problem is occasionally my work pc will restart overnight while emails are open. Not sure why yet but I'd like a way to look up which emails may have been opened at the time. I envision this "look up" as a scheduled written text file listing the Subject fields of open emails. Another way could be to schedule an export of the opened emails at 4 PM when I leave work. The /restore switch in Outlook startup won't reopen the emails because it appears the pc goes through a graceful shutdown, not a crash. Dmitry has a solution I could try but I'd welcome anything you may suggest as well.

Answer (score 0):

Trap the `Application.Inspectors.NewInspector` event an read the `Inspector.CurrenmtItem.Subject` property. Reading pane needs to be handled separately.